# Chef-zero provision: unlocated cookbook

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra

I'm getting this message:

```
==> default: ================================================================================
==> default: Recipe Compile Error
==> default: ================================================================================
==> default:
==> default: Chef::Exceptions::RecipeNotFound
==> default: --------------------------------
==> default: could not find recipe default for cookbook olingo
==> default: System Info:
==> default: ------------
==> default: chef_version=13.6.4
==> default: platform=centos
==> default: platform_version=7.4.1708
==> default: ruby=ruby 2.4.2p198 (2017-09-14 revision 59899) [x86_64-linux]
==> default: program_name=chef-client worker: ppid=4729;start=20:31:47;
==> default: executable=/opt/chef/bin/chef-client
```

As you can see, chef is not able to find `olingo` cookbook.

My vagrant chef-zero provision section is:

```
config.vm.provision "chef_zero" do |chef|
  chef.cookbooks_path = "berks-cookbooks"
  chef.data_bags_path = "data_bags"
  chef.nodes_path = "nodes"
  chef.roles_path = "roles"

  chef.add_recipe "olingo"   <<<<1>>>>
end
```

As you can see at `<<<<1>>>>`, I've specified that chef installs `olingo` cookbook. As you can see, I'm using `chef-zero` as well.

In order to download all cookbook dependencies, I'm using berkshelf tool. So I've created a `Berksfile`:

```
source 'https://supermarket.chef.io'
metadata
```

and `metadata.rb`:

```
name 'olingo'   <<<2>>>
maintainer 'The Authors'
maintainer_email 'you@example.com'
license 'all_rights'
description 'Installs/Configures webapi'
long_description 'Installs/Configures webapi'
version '0.1.0'

depends 'java_se', '~> 8.141.0'
depends 'wildfly', '~> 0.4.0'
```

So, then I perform `berks vendor` and a `berks-cookbooks` folder is created filled with all olingo **dependencies**, but no `olingo` cookbook is located there.

So, it seems `olingo` cookbook is not available when `chef_client` tries to install `olingo` cookbook.

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of berkshelf are you using?. There was a bug few weeks ago, where berkshelf had serious issues with dependency solving and dependent cookbook were not dowloaded. Also, message says there is no **default recipe**, but this may be missleading.

Comment: I think the problem is that, in fact, there's no a `olingo` cookbook. `olingo` is the name specified on `metadata.rb` (`<<<2>>>`). I think that something else is necessary... so I mean, `berks vendor` downloads all dependencies at `berks-cookbooks` folder, but there's no a `olingo` cookbook there. I don't know if I've explained so well...

Comment: Do you see `olingo` in the `Berksfile.lock`?